# Elasticsearch maintenance an unique _id across the aliases

Tags: elasticsearch, alias

We have ES data where we have several indexes belong to the same alias. One of them is a written index.

How can we keep the _id of documents is unique across the indexes belong to the same alias?

We are right now having a duplicated _id on our alias. Each index has 1 record of the same id. We only want the lastest record of that _id on our data, the newer will overwrite the older.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand the problem, you can have uniqueness of data by using _id value as a fingerprint value via logstash [ assuming its being used].

You can have something like the below in your logstash filter:

```
fingerprint{
            source => ["session_id"]
            method => "SHA1"                        
            }
```

This value in the fingerprint field can then be used to put the data in an index and updated on top of an already existing document.

Below is an example of output section in logstash:

```
    elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
                index => "indexname"
                action => "update"
                document_id => "%{fingerprint}"
                doc_as_upsert => true
                }
```

Comment: This approach is working under the index level. But I'm talking about alias level, I'm using alias to insert docs to the elasticsearch.
I'm using the rollover policy to rollover the index day by day. For example:
I have the alias call: "Info_write", client will write the data into that alias without knowing which index nname will be written. 
And for performance, the indexes under that alias is being rolled over day by day. So everyday the written index is changed. I wanted to have the unique _id across these indexes belong to the alias.